# Dataflow template job FAIL cause of GCS Problem

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

my jod id is

> 2019-02-01_06_50_27-10838491598599390366

this is dataflow batch job. with template.

here is the dataflow error code.

---

2019-02-01 23:51:02.647 JST
EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
2019-02-01 23:51:02.659 JST
EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
2019-02-01 23:51:02.699 JST
EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
2019-02-01 23:51:02.699 JST
EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
2019-02-01 23:51:02.700 JST
EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
2019-02-01 23:51:02.710 JST
EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
2019-02-01 23:51:02.937 JST
EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
2019-02-01 23:51:03.387 JST
EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
2019-02-01 23:51:10.509 JST
Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system
2019-02-01 23:51:10.511 JST
Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /
{
 insertId:  "s=51b724ba020b4384acc382e634e62cbc;i=568;b=879cba75f5cd4eff82751e8f30ef312b;m=9a91b9;t=580d6461241e4;x=6549465094b7bc54"
 jsonPayload: {…}
 labels: {…}
 logName:  "projects/fluted-airline-109810/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fkubelet"
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-02-01T14:51:18.883283433Z"
 resource: {…}
 severity:  "ERROR"
 timestamp:  "2019-02-01T14:51:10.511494Z"
}
2019-02-01 23:51:10.560 JST
[ContainerManager]: Fail to get rootfs information unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:10.577 JST
Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system
2019-02-01 23:51:10.580 JST
Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:10.608 JST
[ContainerManager]: Fail to get rootfs information unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:10.645 JST
Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system
2019-02-01 23:51:10.646 JST
Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:10.694 JST
[ContainerManager]: Fail to get rootfs information unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:10.749 JST
Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system
2019-02-01 23:51:10.751 JST
Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:10.775 JST
Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system
2019-02-01 23:51:10.777 JST
Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:10.785 JST
[ContainerManager]: Fail to get rootfs information unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:10.809 JST
Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system
2019-02-01 23:51:10.811 JST
Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:10.816 JST
[ContainerManager]: Fail to get rootfs information unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:10.857 JST
[ContainerManager]: Fail to get rootfs information unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:10.929 JST
Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system
2019-02-01 23:51:10.931 JST
Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:10.966 JST
[ContainerManager]: Fail to get rootfs information unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:11.214 JST
Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system
2019-02-01 23:51:11.216 JST
Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:11.254 JST
[ContainerManager]: Fail to get rootfs information unable to find data for container /
2019-02-01 23:51:15.619 JST
PercpuUsage had 0 cpus, but the actual number is 2; ignoring extra CPUs
2019-02-01 23:51:15.793 JST
PercpuUsage had 0 cpus, but the actual number is 2; ignoring extra CPUs
2019-02-01 23:51:15.974 JST
PercpuUsage had 0 cpus, but the actual number is 2; ignoring extra CPUs
2019-02-01 23:51:16.264 JST
PercpuUsage had 0 cpus, but the actual number is 2; ignoring extra CPUs

Answer (score 0):

Is the gs:// bucket accessible by the service account for this job?

Comment: Yes. I'm using that bucket all the time before this problem. But it cannot access suddenly. I can access in web console, but cannot in dataflow. I've been created new bucket in single asia region, then It works. Maybe multiple-region is the cause if this problem. Dataflow temp bucket must use single-region gcs. maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue with any dataflow template that needs to read off of GSC. Dataflow worker account does have storage access so it makes no sense to me why it would see it as a "read-only" directory.